# Getting property value is undefined or null error for JavaScript call in Dynamics CRM 2011

Tags: javascript, dynamics-crm-2011

Just started with Javasript + Dynamics 2011 today and got stuck at the beginning itself. I've been trying simple steps as follow
1. Change the value on radio button
2. Call a function from Javascript, which will set two field enabled and disabled

Code is as follows

```
function navenabled()
{

    var navdata = Xrm.Page.getAttribute("new_currentnavclient").getValue;

    if (navdata == true)
    {
        Xrm.Page.getControl(“new_noofusers”).setDisabled(true);
        Xrm.Page.getControl(“new_navversion”).setDisabled(true);
    }
    else
    {
        Xrm.Page.getControl(“new_noofusers”).setDisabled(false);
                Xrm.Page.getControl(“new_navversion”).setDisabled(false);
    }

}
```

I'm getting the following error, when changing the value on 'Current Nav Client' field

[image]

Also see the steps that I have performed for JavaScript call

[image]

Can someone please tell where I'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 3):

First problem is with this line:

```js
var navdata = Xrm.Page.getAttribute("new_currentnavclient").getValue;
```

`getValue` is a method, so the right way is `getValue()`

```js
var navdata = Xrm.Page.getAttribute("new_currentnavclient").getValue();
```

The second problem is with all the `getControl` lines, you are using smart quotes

```
“ ”
```

Instead you need to use simple quotation marks, so your code will be:

```js
function navenabled()
{

    var navdata = Xrm.Page.getAttribute("new_currentnavclient").getValue();

    if (navdata == true)
    {
        Xrm.Page.getControl("new_noofusers").setDisabled(true);
        Xrm.Page.getControl("new_navversion").setDisabled(true);
    }
    else
    {
        Xrm.Page.getControl("new_noofusers").setDisabled(false);
        Xrm.Page.getControl("new_navversion").setDisabled(false);
    }

}
```

Comment: Great- thanks! My problem has been solved. But this JavaScript is behaving unexpected and the error information is not valuable. Do you have any idea how to debug the JavaScript code properly on Google chrome.

Comment: you can google for "crm 2011 debug javascript" you will find several guides to debug, mostly with IE

Answer (score 0):

What you can try to do is using the document.getElementById ("fieldname").checked property. This value is allways accurate.

Comment: document.getElementById is an unsupported customization, and for get values and manage controls there are the supported Xrm methods

Comment: Unsupported, what can I say, so be it. A long time ago I followed a course from Microsoft. They worked out a complete example. Turning to the next page it says. Keep in mind that this is unsupported.

Comment: Well, the teacher of the course you followed didn't tell you a more important rule: If there is a supported method to do one thing, use that.